# Tables autofit column widths based on original contents regardless of directives

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

Consider you write a document using Sphinx 2.x and create a table in it. Put directives in some table cells like this:

```
No directive (good)

+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Country | Cities                                                                                                   |
+=========+==========================================================================================================+
| UK      | London, Leeds, Glasgow, Sheffield, Bradford, Manchester, Edinburgh, Liverpool, Bristol, Cardiff, Belfast |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| US      | New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Houston, Phoenix, Philadelphia, San Antonio, San Diego, Dallas, San Jose |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


With the directive (bad)

.. |the_united_kingdom_of_great_britain_and_northern_ireland| replace:: UK

+------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Country                                                    | Cities                                                                                                   |
+============================================================+==========================================================================================================+
| |the_united_kingdom_of_great_britain_and_northern_ireland| | London, Leeds, Glasgow, Sheffield, Bradford, Manchester, Edinburgh, Liverpool, Bristol, Cardiff, Belfast |
+------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| US                                                         | New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Houston, Phoenix, Philadelphia, San Antonio, San Diego, Dallas, San Jose |
+------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Compare these two tables: the only difference is that the substitute (replace) directive for *"UK"* is used in the second table.

I believe these two tables must appear the same. But it's not.

**HTML**

[image: a make html result]

**rst2pdf**

[image: rst2pdf]

I expect the table autofit operations take place in the following order:

1. Create a table
2. Evaluate directives in it
3. Resize the table (particularly, column widths)

But both HTML and rst2pdf seem to be performing

1. Create a table
2. Resize the table (particularly, column widths)
3. Evaluate directives in it

Is this as-designed? Is there any way to (re)optimize the column widths for the second table?

Answer (score 0):

View the HTML source and you will see what is happening with `width: ##%` for each column.

```
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 8%">
<col style="width: 92%">
</colgroup>
```

and

```
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 36%">
<col style="width: 64%">
</colgroup>
```

Try a custom style:

```
table.docutils>colgroup {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to take a control before Sphinx converts the rst files to HTML, PDF, etc.?  I agree I can update colgroup tags in HTML products by making a custom CSS code as you've suggested. I can also use the sed command to find and replace those part of HTML srtings. But it would be messier if the product is PDF.

Comment: Minor point: Sphinx uses docutils, which converts rst. You would have to dive neck deep into docutils, which is not my idea of a good time.